# linkedin-j authorization failed

Tags: java, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

i work with the linkedin-j lib and try to authorize, but there always an exception is thrown:

I try to authorize first. But if i fetch the

```
request
```

and the

```
authURL
```

an exception is thrown(see below).

This is my code:

```
private static String consumerKeyValue="[mykey]";
private static String consumerSecretValue="[mySecret]";
private static String accessTokenValue="[myTokenValue]";
private static String tokenSecretValue="[mytokenSecretValue]";

static LinkedInApiClientFactory factory;
static LinkedInApiClient client;

static LinkedInOAuthService oAuthService;
static LinkedInRequestToken request;
static String authURL;

private static LinkedInAccessToken accessToken;

public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{

    authorize(consumerKeyValue, tokenSecretValue);
    createClient(consumerKeyValue, consumerSecretValue, accessTokenValue, tokenSecretValue);

}


public static void createClient(String key, String secret, String token, String secretToken){
factory=LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(key,secret);
client=factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);
}

public static void authorize(String key, String secret) throws IOException{
    oAuthService=LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(key, secret);
    request=oAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken();
    authURL=request.getAuthorizationUrl();
    System.out.println("Paste this URL to your browser:");
    System.out.println(authURL);
    System.out.println("and now paste the given PIN here and press enter");
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String input=br.readLine();
    accessToken =oAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken(request, input);
}


}
```

and now following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceException: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken
at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.java:159)
at Connection.authorize(Connection.java:46)
at Connection.main(Connection.java:32)
Caused by: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken
at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)
at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.java:148)
... 2 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at oauth.signpost.basic.HttpURLConnectionResponseAdapter.getContent(HttpURLConnectionResponseAdapter.java:18)
at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.handleUnexpectedResponse(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:228)
at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:189)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at oauth.signpost.basic.HttpURLConnectionResponseAdapter.getStatusCode(HttpURLConnectionResponseAdapter.java:22)
at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:178)
... 4 more
```

Comment: HTTP 401 is Unhautorized check your key/secret values.

Comment: @BigMike Can you tell me what should i use or these fields consumerKeyValue, consumerSecretValue,accessTokenValue,tokenSecretValue from linkedin API. I got the same above error

Comment: depends on when you have the error. OAUTH works in steps, first you need to obtain a token (providing consumerKeyValues), then you need to use the token to perform operations.